# Inserting relational data using Dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two tables with Pk and Fk relationship.When i insert into one table(EventLog table) i get a logID(autogenerated) now i need to insert into the second table (EventErrorLog table).

The addrow method

```
public LOG_FIRE_EventLogErrorRow AddLOG_FIRE_EventLogErrorRow(
    LOG_FIRE_EventLogRow parentLOG_FIRE_EventLogRowByFK_LOG_FIRE_EventLogError_LOG_FIRE_EventLog,
    string errorDescription
)
```

need a row from EventLog table.How do pass that?

Answer (score 1):

Check:

http://web.archive.org/web/20080531012216/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/can-sql-server-tell-me-which-row-was-inserted-most-recently.html